# get content slot as string with Vue js 2

Tags: vue.js

I need get string inside slot before that slot is compiled. Is posibble?

Example

```
<div>
 <slot>
   <component-test text="test1"></component-test>    
 </slot>   
</div>
```

I need as result `"<component-test text="test1"></component-test>"`

Answer (score -1):

hmm seems its treating slot content html so .. in end result if you need it as string and use later on then you have to do some trick.

first you need to put real string there:

```
escape('<component-test text="test1"></component-test>');
```

output : %3Ccomponent-test%20text%3D%22test1%22%3E%3C/component-test%3E

use this output content and put that in slot.
this will treat as string.

now if you need to use that string's real html

convert it back to html using :

```
unescape('%3Ccomponent-test%20text%3D%22test1%22%3E%3C/component-test%3E')
```

output :

```
<component-test text="test1"></component-test>
```

in this way when you need to transfer html/string you can make it real string then when you need to use/compile make it html again.